# C# Close TCP channel in a form

Tags: c#

How to close the TCP Channel in a form after I have close the form , and I want to open the form again to start TCP Channel using the same form. But it return an error message telling that the TCP Channel has been registered. I have try few ways to close this form only but return fail as Application.Exit is closing whole application

```
private void EstablishRemote()
            {
                SoapServerFormatterSinkProvider soap = new SoapServerFormatterSinkProvider();
                BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider binary = new BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider();
                soap.TypeFilterLevel = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.TypeFilterLevel.Full;
                binary.TypeFilterLevel = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.TypeFilterLevel.Full;

                soap.Next = binary;

                Hashtable table = new Hashtable();
                table.Add("port", ServerPortValue.Text);

                TcpChannel channel = new TcpChannel(table, null, soap);

                FTPServer.Logger = Logger;

                ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel,false);
                RemotingConfiguration.ApplicationName = "FTPServerAPP";
                RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(typeof(FTPServer),"ftpserver.svr", WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton);

                Logger.Text += Environment.NewLine+ "***** TCP Channel has been published... *****";

            }

    private void StartServer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ServerPortValue.Text))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter server port.", "Server", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                    return;
                }
                EstablishRemote();
                ServerPortValue.ReadOnly  = true;
                StartServer.Enabled = false;
                ServerStatusMessage.Text = "Server has been started...";
            }
```

Comment: You can register a channel only once.  Clearly you are looking for the UnregisterChannel() method.  Call it from your FormClosed event handler if it makes sense to get rid of the channel when the form closes.  Which is rather unusual.

Comment: yes, get rid channel once the form closed. but when i put the UnregisterChannel() method in the formclosed event handler, it show this error "The name 'channel' does not exist in the current context". so is there any advice on it?